# How to deal with "Ergänzungsstrichen" and "Bindestrichen" in German NLP?

Tags: nlp, tokenization

#### Problem

In German, the phrase "Haupt- und Nebensatz" has exactly the same meaning as "Hauptsatz und Nebensatz". However, when transforming both phrases using e.g. spacy's [`de_core_news_sm`](https://spacy.io/models/de#de_core_news_sm) pipeline, the cosine similarity of the resulting vectors differs significantly:

| token1 | token2 | similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Haupt- | Hauptsatz | 0.07 |
| und | und | 0.67 |
| Nebensatz | Nebenssatz | 0.87 |

Code to reproduce

```py
import spacy
import numpy as np


def calc_cosine_similarity(a, b):
    return np.dot(a, b) / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b))


nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
doc1 = nlp("Hauptsatz und Nebensatz")
doc2 = nlp("Haupt- und Nebensatz")
for token1, token2 in zip(doc1, doc2):
    similarity = calc_cosine_similarity(token1.vector, token2.vector)
    print(f"{token1.text}: {similarity}")
```

#### My research for a solution

This [Bachelorthesis](https://wwwmatthes.in.tum.de/file/12kcbte1ld3i9/Sebis-Public-Website/-/Bachelor-s-Thesis-Patrick-Ruoff/Bachelorarbeit_Ruoff.pdf) states on page 5:

> A distinction is made between phrases with a complementary dash, as in "main and subordinate clauses", and those with a hyphen, as in "price-performance ratio". The former are divided into several tokens, the latter form a single one. (translated from original German)

This sounds like a preprocessing solution is readily available? However, so far I could not find any yet on e.g. https://github.com/adbar/German-NLP , but I might have overlooked things.

Answer (score 0):

Tested [bert-base-german-cased](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-cased) from huggingface today. The results are still different, but much more similar. Also, the tokenizer splits words in a desired way. This might already work for my use case, so marking the question as answered.

| token1 | token2 | cos-similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [CLS] | [CLS] | 0.982 |
| Haupt | Haupt | 0.933 |
| - | ##satz | 0.824 |
| und | und | 0.967 |
| Neben | Neben | 0.951 |
| ##satz | ##satz | 0.958 |
| [SEP] | [SEP] | 0.977 |

Code to reproduce:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel, AutoModel
import numpy as np

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-german-cased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-german-cased")

def calc_cosine_similarity(a, b):
    return np.dot(a, b) / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b))

def calc_bert_embeddings(text):
  """Returns a (N,768) vector representing embeddings for the N tokens."""
  tokens = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt') 
  output = model(**tokens)
  return tokens.tokens(), output["last_hidden_state"][0,:,:].detach().numpy()

tokens1, vec1 = calc_bert_embeddings("Haupt- und Nebensatz")
tokens2, vec2 = calc_bert_embeddings("Hauptsatz und Nebensatz")
for idx in range(len(tokens1)):
  similarity = calc_cosine_similarity(vec1[idx,:], vec2[idx,:])
  print(f"{tokens1[idx]};{tokens2[idx]};{similarity:.3f}")
```